# Using CUFFT in cuda

Tags: cuda

I am trying to find fft using cufft for 2,500 points of data type doublereal with 20,000 data points each. I used:

```
cufftHandle plan;

cufftPlan1d(&plan, 20000, CUFFT_D2Z, 2500) ;

cufftExecD2Z(plan, source, result);
```

The code seems to work fine when the number of data points are up to 15000. But above it, the results are not accurate. I found out that I can have 2^27 data points in 1D array, but 20000*2500 is still less than 2^27. Can someone point out what the error is and what must be done to correct it?

Answer (score 1):

`cufftPlan1d()` for batch processing is marked as deprecated (in cuda 6.0 and later, maybe already earlier?), see http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cufft/index.html#function-cufftmakeplan1d.

Did you try to use the recommended `cufftPlanMany()`? 
For your example the plan should look like this:

```
int size[1] = {20000};
cufftPlanMany( &plan, 1, size, NULL, 0, 0, NULL, 0, 0, CUFFT_D2Z, 2500 );
```

For more information about the parameters see http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cufft/index.html#function-cufftplanmany.